# socket refused to connect to ip specified

Tags: python, sockets

I'm getting the error:

> ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused

```
import socket

def socket_to_me():

     socket.setdefaulttimeout(10)
     s = socket.socket()
     s.connect(("127.0.0.1",21))
     ans = s.recv(1024)
     print(ans)
```

Comment: Please, add more explanation to your question?...How are you running your script?..Is there another connection established to that same IP address?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you chose the right IP Address (Try it with the name or the IPv6 Address, might help) and the right port? 21 is the reserved port for FTP, so this might be a problem
Good luck, hopefully you'll find a solution soon!